# Failing to pass a complex object from one page to another in .Net Maui

Tags: maui

I am trying to pass a complex object from MainPage to a ProductsPage, the object is a model with 4 class lists. Of the 4 class lists only 2 are passing data to the ProductsPage, the other 2 are not. I dont know where i am going wrong, i am using MVVM

My MainPageViewModel is as below

```
public partial class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<LogInModel> LogInModels { get; } = new();

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {

        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        LogInModel logInModel;

        [RelayCommand]
        async Task GoToRetailAsync()
        {
            if (LogInModels.Count != 0)
                LogInModels.Clear();

            LogInModels.Add(logInModel);
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ProductsPage)}", true,
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                 {
                    {"shiptoo",LogInModels[0].cat },
                    {"group",LogInModels[0].grp },
                    {"products",LogInModels[0].prod },
                    {"shipto",LogInModels[0].shp }
                 });

            
        }
       
    }
}
```

the failing class lists are shiptoo and group

Below is my ProductsViewModel

```
namespace Tenga.ViewModel
{
    [QueryProperty("Products", "products")]
    [QueryProperty("Group","group")]
    [QueryProperty("Shiptoo","shiptoo")]
    [QueryProperty("Shipto", "shipto")]

    public partial class ProductsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ProductsViewModel()
        {

        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        List<Shiptoo> shppp;
        [ObservableProperty]
        List<Group> groups;
        [ObservableProperty]
        List<Products> products;
        [ObservableProperty]
        List<Shipto> shipto;
    }
}
```

Below is my LogInModel

```
namespace Tenga.Model
{ 
    public class LogInModel
    {
        public string OTP { get; set; }
        public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string Balance { get; set; }
        public string OpenToBuy { get; set; }
        public string CreditLimit { get; set; }
        public string LoginStatus { get; set; }
        public string Error { get; set; }
        public List<Shipto> shp = new List<Shipto>();
        public List<Shiptoo> cat = new List<Shiptoo>();
        public List<Group> grp = new List<Group>();
        public List<Products> prod = new List<Products>();
    }

    public class Shipto
    {
        public string ShipCode { get; set; }
        public string ShipDescription { get; set; }
    }
    public class Products
    {
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        public string UOM { get; set; }
        public string ConversionFactor { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    }
    public class Shiptoo
    {
        public string ShipCode { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    }
    public class Group
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have tried to review the class all seems alright, i have also tried changing the bindings and result is the same, can some one please help before  go crazy

Comment: In your ProductsViewModel you have the properties shppp and group instead of groups and shiptoo. I assume that are the missing passed List

Comment: Yes those 2 are the ones that are not passing data to my productsPage, products and shipto are ok

Comment: @TheTanic is pointing out that the names do not match, that is why they are not working

Comment: Thank you guys very very much geeez i could not see those differences. So so grateful for your help guys

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Implement IQueryAttributable in your ViewModel.

And use:

```
public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
{
      Model = query[nameof(MyModel )] as MyModel ;
}
```

Forget about those annotations. This is better. You cant mistake names, you can run code after/before they are set. I migrated all my code to use this.

Edit: While we are on the subject:

Instead of:

```
{"shiptoo",LogInModels[0].cat },
```

You should be using some constants. The name of the model usually. (Something like naming conventions when passing Extras in android, but much more simple).

Comment: Thank you will look into implementing IQueryAttributable